# Approximation of continuous function by uniform convergence of piecewise constant functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am reading Analysis 2 by Terence Tao, and I have a question regarding approximating continuous functions by piecewise constant functions.

Suppose that $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$. Can you find a sequence of piecewise constant functions $(f_n)$ such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ $\textbf{uniformly}$? I know that this can be done such that $f_n$ converges pointwise, but I am not sure about uniform convergence. My intuition tells me that I can do this when $f$ has a bounded support, but I am not sure. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this if and only if $f(x)$ has  finite limits at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm By finite limits, do you mean that $f$ is a bounded function?

Comment: @geetha290krm Would you happen to have a reference for this? I do believe continuity of $f$ is sufficient, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @WillowWisp Can you approximate the identity function uniformly by piece-wise constant functions?

Comment: I am assuming that a piece-wise constant function takes finite number of constant values. If you allow infinitely many constant values then a N & S condition is uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah I see, I assumed $f_n$ wasn't required to take finitely many constant values. But now it is this N&S condition that I am unfamiliar with. It seems to me we could build sub-intervals that cover the whole real line without assuming uniform continuity.

Comment: @naveenraj03 I do believe it is possible with just the continuity of $f$, so here's a hint to start with: usually the sub-intervals on which $f_n$ is constant are of the same size, but not necessarily here. The trick here is to first define them systematically so that $f_n$ never strays too far from $f$.

Comment: @WillowWisp Thank you for the hint, but could you give a little more detail about the construction of these intervals. Everything I've done so far uses dyadic intervals, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @geetha290krm what would the pieces of the piece-wise constant function be? I am guessing that the pieces will closed sets or open sets. Is there any way to make the pieces to be left open-right closed intervals??

Comment: To approximate uniformly continuous functions by piece-wise constant functions you can use intervals of any type.

Comment: @geetha290krm If I may bother you one last time. Could you briefly give an idea of how would the construction would be like??

Comment: @naveenraj03 Actually I realized there's probably a simpler way to picture it. You can first solve the problem for $f \in C([0,1])$, for which you can use dyadic sub-intervals if you'd like (since $f$ is necessarily uniformly continuous over $[0,1]$). Then, for $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$, you can use the same arguments over each interval $[k,k+1]$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and stitch your $f_n$'s together that way.